# Finding the number of roots which are real

Tags: rational-functions

Let $0<a_1<a_2< . . . <a_n$ be real numbers .I need to show that the equation 
$$
\frac{a_1}{a_1-x}  + \cdots +\frac{a_n}{a_n-x}=2015 
$$
has exactly $n$ real roots.

Please tell me the steps, do I need to simplify the equation? It seems painful to me. Please dont solve the question

Comment: My first guess would be to try an inductive argument. Have you done this?

Comment: The question doesn't say it has no complex roots, only that there are $n$ real roots.

Comment: No I haven't tried out inductively although 

Comment: @saulspatz the equation is of degree n so at max it is having n real roots

Comment: Have you thought about what the graph looks like?

Comment: You're right about the number of roots.  I was just about to delete my comment, but you beat me to it by an eyelash.  I think looking at the graph will be helpful, though.

Comment: @saulspatz can you please provide your statements in the form of an answer. It will definitely help me. Shall be thankful to you if you do the needful

Comment: @Stan Tendijick how can I go about inductively if I am to prove it for $n+1$ . Please provide an answer to this part only . I have seen that for n=1 the linear equation is having  root which is real

Comment: I would show this via intermediate value theorem. You can find $n+1$ "flips", locations where the parity of the function changes (from <2015 to >2015). I won't detail how to do this as this is the point of the problem, but this is a nice hint.

Comment: The graph should be having n asymptotes, and since the derivative is positive the graph between these asymptotes should be strictly increasing . Now I can manage using IVT . Thanks for your cooperation guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i\over a_i-x}$$ is continuous except at the points $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n.$  When $x$ is close to $a_i$ but smaller than $a_i, \ f(x)$ is very large ("goes to $\infty.$")  When $x$ is close to $a_i$ but larger than $a_i$ then $f(x)$ goes to $-\infty.$  Now you need to examine the behavior of $f(x)$ when $x$ is greater than all the $a_i$ and when $x$ is smaller than all the $a_i$ and you can sketch the graph.  Then just count the number of times it crosses the line $y=2015.$

If you have difficulty seeing how to do this for a general $n$, start by doing it for $n=3$ say.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz

Comment: Your solution should invoke a theorem of analysis, i.e., the intermediate values theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-2015$.

(see illustration below).

Reducing $g(x)$ do a same denominator gives a rational fraction which is $0$ if and only if its numerator is $0$. And this numerator is clearly a $n$th degree polynomial.

We are going first to find $n-1$ roots...

Indeed, on each interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$, one has

$$\lim_{x \to a_i+0} \ g(x)=-\infty+A=-\infty$$

where $A:=\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_i}-2015,$

whereas :

$$\lim_{x \to a_{i+1}-0} \ g(x)=+\infty+B=+\infty$$

where $B:=\sum_{j=1, j\neq (i+1)}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_{i+1}}-2015.$

Thus, by continuity of $g$ on interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$, there is at least a real root of $f$ on this interval (intermediate values theorem). See remark below.

Thus we have found at least one root on each interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$. It remains to find the last one (we are at Easter time : looking for the last egg...).

Is it "hidden" in $(-\infty,a_1)$ or $(a_n,+\infty)$ ?

Up to you (you have said you don't want a full solution...).

[image]

*Fig. 1 : An illustration with $g(x):=\dfrac{2}{2-x}+\dfrac{3}{3-x}+\dfrac{5}{5-x}-10$ (we have taken $10$ instead of $2015$ because the latter is too big). Axes are black, asymptotes are red.*

Remark : [in fact there is only one root by interval, because $g$ is increasing on each interval, but we don't need it].

Comment: Excellent answer I was expecting IVT application here thanks

Comment: I just added a graphical representation.

Comment: Nice graphical representation out there

Answer (score 0):

A proof by contradiction.

This  is  a  polynomial  of degree  n  on  x.  So,  there  are  n  number of  roots. We  have  to  prove that  n  roots  are  real. There  is  no  complex root  of the  equation. Let,  there  are  two  complex roots  $s  + ir$  and $ s  –  ir$  (As  complex  roots  come in conjugate  pair)

Now, $ s  + ir $will  satisfy  the  equation.

a1/(a1  –  s  –  ir)  + a2/(a2  –  s  –  ir)  + ....  + an/(an  –  s  –  ir)  = 2015

Similarly,  a1/(a1  –  s  + ir)  + a2/(a2  –  s  +  ir)  + .....  + an/(an  –  s  + ir)  = 2015

Now,  subtracting  the  equations  we  get,

{a1/(a1  –  s  –  ir)  –  a1/(a1  –  s  + ir)}  + {a2/(a2  –  s  –  ir)  –  a2/(a2  –  s  + ir)}  + .....  +  {an/(an  –  s  –  ir)  –  an/(an  –  s  + ir)}  = 2015  –  2015

a1(2ir)/{(a1  –  s)2  +  r2} +  a2(2ir)/{(a2  –  s)2  + r2}  + ..... +  an(2ir)/{(an  –  s)2  +  r2} =  0

(2ir)[a1/{(a1  –  s)2  + r2}  + a2/(a2  –  s)2  + r2}+......+ an/{(an  –  s)2  + r2}]  = 0

Now,  a1,  a2,  ...,  an  all  are  greater than  0. The  expression  inside  the  square  bracket  is  greater  than  0  as denominators are  sum  of square  numbers and  greater than  $0$  . $r$ has  to  be  $0$.  The  imaginary part  of  the  roots  are  zero.  The  roots  are  no  more  complex.  Our assumption  was  wrong.  There  is  no  complex root  of the  equation.  All  roots  are  real.  There  are  $n $ number of  real  roots.

Comment: Can this be also a suitable method?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used MathJax  , I was in a hurry to show if my attempt is correct or not

Comment: No, you don't need to argue about complex roots because expression $g(x)=f(x)-2015$ is the partial fraction decomposition of a rational fraction $N(x)/D(x)$ with deg(N)=deg(D)=n which is $0$ if and only if its denominator is zero ; as we are able to find $n$ real roots for $N(x)=0$, there is no place for complex roots (a polynomial with degree $n$ has $n$ roots, here all distinct).