# Is there a way to solve for $x$ in $c = \operatorname{mean}\left(\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_ix}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I'm trying to simplify this problem $c = \operatorname{mean}\left(\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_ix}\right)$ to solve for $x$. Right now the way I'm doing it is basically trying a bunch of $x$ values and seeing which one is closest to $c$, but I was wondering if there's a way to solve for $x$ directly. I tried this:
$$
c = \frac 1 n \sum_i^n \frac{a_i}{a_i+b_ix} \\
cn = \sum_i^n \frac{a_i}{a_i+b_ix} \\
cn = \sum_i^n a_i \prod_{j \neq i} (a_j + b_jx)
$$

But for large $i$ this would be a large, intractable polynomial, right? Are there any other ideas that might help? Thanks.

Comment: Any additional constraints? E.g., are perhaps all $a_i,b_i$ positive?

Comment: maybe you could use Newton instead of just trying a bunch?

Comment: Let $\,c_i=-a_i/b_i\,$ and assume WLOG that the sequence is ascending. The equation will have one root in each interval $\,(c_i,c_{i+1})\,$ and one more root elsewhere, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210991/finding-the-number-of-roots-which-are-real) for example. You can first find which interval $\,c\,$ falls into, then find the closest roots to it numerically.